# Javascript - Find largest area in a matrix

Tags: javascript, matrix, multidimensional-array, area

The task is: Find the largest area of identical numbers in a matrix.

The matrix is hardcoded and i have the following code so far.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<script type="text/javascript">
    /* ---- Function that prints a matrix and finds the largest area and its value  ---- */
            function LargestAreaMatrix() {

                var matrix = [[1,3,2,2,2,4],
                              [4,3,2,2,4,4],
                              [4,4,1,2,3,3],
                              [4,3,1,2,3,1],
                              [4,3,3,2,2,1]];

                var arrSize = matrix.length;
                var itemSize = matrix[0].length;
                var counter = {};

                for (var i = 0; i < arrSize; i++ ){
                    for (var j = 0; j < itemSize; j++) {
                                //if the current element is equal to the next element   
                                if (matrix[i][j] == matrix[i][j+1]) {
                                    //to the object "key" is assigned the current value of the matrix and the "value" is incrementing till the condition is true  
                                    counter[matrix[i][j]] = 1 + (counter[matrix[i][j]] || 0);
                                    console.log("Right neighbor: "+ matrix[i][j] + " - ij: " + i + " " + j);
                                } 
                                if (typeof(matrix[i+1]) != "undefined" ) {
                                    //if the current element is equal to the bottom element
                                    if (matrix[i][j] == matrix[i+1][j]) {
                                        // the value of the specific key is incrementing
                                        counter[matrix[i][j]] = 1 + (counter[matrix[i][j]] || 0);
                                        console.log("Down neighbor:  "+ matrix[i][j] + " - ij: " + i + " " + j);
                                    }
                                } else {
                                    console.log("Not a neighbor: "+ matrix[i][j] + " - ij: " + i + " " + j);
                                } 
                    }//end of for j
                }//end of for i


                console.log("Neighbors count: ");
                console.log(counter);   


                //Printing the array with an html table
                var table = '<table border="0">';
                for (var i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
                    table += '<tr>';
                    for (var j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; j++) {
                        table += '<td>' + matrix[i][j] + '</td>';
                    }
                    table += '</tr>';
                }
                table += '</table>';

                document.getElementById('matrix').innerHTML = table;
            }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p></p>
<p><a href="#" onClick="LargestAreaMatrix();">Largest Area Matrix</a></p>
<label name="matrix" id="matrix"> </label>
</body>
</html>
```

I made 2 loops for going through the matrix where i check for right and down neighbors. If there are any - i use an object to put the value of the matrix for a key, while the object value is incrementing with the count of the key.
So in the end i have the count of the neighbors for every value.

My questions: For some reason, in the outside loop, where "i" hits 4 (the matrix size) both the second if and the else are executed. Why is this happening? 
Also - I am still trying to figure out how to make it count only the largest area, not all the neighbors for a specific value.

I will appreciate any help. Thanks!

Update:

So it turned out to be simpler than i thought it will be :) 
Here is the recursive function i made to count the size of each area:

```
                function findNeighbors(row, col, item){
                if(row < 0 || col < 0 || row > (arrSize - 1) || col > (itemSize - 1)) {
                    return 0;
                }

                if(matrixZero[row][col] == 1) {
                    return 0;
                }

                if(item == matrix[row][col]){
                    matrixZero[row][col] = 1;
                    tempCount = 1 + (findNeighbors(row, col+1, matrix[row][col]) || 0) + (findNeighbors(row+1, col, matrix[row][col]) || 0) + (findNeighbors(row, col-1, matrix[row][col]) || 0) + (findNeighbors(row-1, col, matrix[row][col]) || 0);
                    return tempCount;
                }
            }
```

First i check if the current item is in the matrix range, if not - 0 is added to the tempCount value. Then i check if the item is already visited, if yes - 0 is added to the temp. Then if the item in neither visited, neither out of the matrix i check it as visited and add 1 to the temp and etc.

Then in a simple for I compare the tempCount value with the current max value and i switch them if temp is higher than max.

Thanks everyone for the help!

Comment: I'm not seeing anything odd happening... https://jsfiddle.net/g90powkv/ when i = 4, I see "right neighbor" and "not a neighbor", indicating that only the else block is executed, rather than both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you code is doing something weird. But maybe you are not using the best logic for that. Here's a working function. If you are a beginner, you can read this code.

```
function LargestAreaMatrix() {

  var matrix = [[1,3,2,2,2,4],
                [4,3,2,2,4,4],
                [4,4,1,2,3,3],
                [4,3,1,2,3,1],
                [4,3,3,2,2,1]];

  var cache = {};

  function pulse(x, y) {
    var queue = [],
        visited = {},
        size = 0;

    // Current cell is the first element
    queue.push({
      'x' : x,
      'y' : y
    });
    visited[x + ' ' + y] = true;
    size = 1;

    function test(x, y, value) {
      if (!visited[x + ' ' + y] && y >= 0 && y < matrix.length && x >= 0 && x < matrix[y].length && matrix[y][x] == value) {
        queue.push({
          'x' : x,
          'y' : y
        });
        visited[x + ' ' + y] = true;
        size += 1;
      }
    }

    while (queue.length) {
      var cell = queue.pop(),
          value = matrix[cell.y][cell.x];

      // Add neighbors of the same value to the queue
      test(cell.x - 1, cell.y, value);
      test(cell.x + 1, cell.y, value);
      test(cell.x, cell.y - 1, value);
      test(cell.x, cell.y + 1, value);
    }

    // Cache the size for all visited cells for performances
    for (var key in visited) {
      cache[key] = size;
    }

    return size;
  }

  var max = 0;

  for (var y = 0; y < matrix.length; ++y) {
    for (var x = 0; x < matrix[y].length; ++x) {
      if (!cache[x + ' ' + y]) {
        var size = pulse(x, y);

        if (size > max) {
          max = size;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  console.log('Largest area size', max);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran your code and it's not that *second if and else* are executed, but *first if and else part of second if statement*.

So in the first *if* you discover that matrix(i,j) is right neighbour and then you go on testing for the down neighbour in the second *if* statement. However, as *i = 4* at this point you're trying to access row *i+1* has to produce *undefined* as there is no *6th* row in the matrix. That's why both first if and else part of second if are hit. Something wrong with the logic I guess..